# Freezer part of KitchenAid fridge not freezing

Tags: repair

Freezer in Kitchenaid side by side fridge stopped making ice,, but will dispense water. Freezer has been emptied and cleaned. When open, I can hear and feel a fan blowing cool air. Have reset circuit breaker and vacuumed lower front coils. Temperature settings for both sections are at max.
Still not cold, and don't seem to hear compressor running, only the soft sound of a fan running. Yesterday fridge part was cool, but now this section is also not cold. What is likely the problem?

Comment: When did you last clean off the cooling fins in the back of the fridge?

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me (the day of my wedding!), the repairman replaced the logic board in the back of the freezer compartment. Problem solved. According to him this is a common failure in KitchenAid side-by-side fridges.